# Use a void method to update an ArrayList in the main method

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I'm in APCSA in school and am running into an issue with the Java Methods Textbook. I'm given a main method that is supposed to call a void with an ArrayList as a parameter. This is supposed to sort the ArrayList and return to the main. I know that Java doesn't pass by reference, so how do I get the void method to update the old ArrayList in the main method to the new sorted one? Also, if there is a way to do this, can you do the same with regular arrays?

EDIT: The ArrayList code ended up working, it had a small error I managed to fix.

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem [here are some tips](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: _"I know that Java doesn't pass by reference..."_ That is correct, Java is always pass-by-value. But, you can still pass a reference by value, and since objects are reference types, the value of an `ArrayList` variable will be a _reference to_ an actual `ArrayList` object. If you pass the reference by value, which copies _the reference_, it will still reference the same object.

Answer (score -1):

If you pass an `ArrayList` as a parameter, and change that `ArrayList` inside of the method, it *will* change the `ArrayList` for the method that passed it in. In Java, objects are passed by reference (note that this will not work for primitives like `int`, since those are passed by value).